# How to show menu name instead "SUB MENU " each page?

Tags: joomla-3.4, extensions, module-display

[image]

Hello
How to show menu name instead "SUB MENU " each page?
Thk.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is the title of the module that you have selected to show that menu.

Search in module manager for a menu module named Sub Menu, click to edit it and change its title.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give that module a title that you want to show, and then Set'Show title' option to 'Yes'. Also you can set the Menu title and show it as well.

But I guess Module option will work for you.